# Cat's fur not growing back after surgery

Tags: cats, grooming

My female cat was spayed approximately two years ago. The fur on the area that was shaved for surgery has never grown back. There is a layer of soft downy fuzz, but nothing more. The demarcation between where she was shaved and where she wasn't is absolutely clear. It's as if she has an "inverse Brazilian"!

I will of course ask the vet about this when I take her for her annual exam, but in the meantime I'm curious about why this might be. She doesn't groom the area excessively, and her skin and the rest of her coat are in excellent condition. The area is not sensitive or tender -- she loves getting belly rubs. She's happy, relaxed, playful, and the picture of health. I feed both of my cats Royal Canin Sensitive (because my other cat can get stressed easily). Is this just one of those things that happens to some cats?

Comment: any chance to post some before and after pics of her fur?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems to be something that does happen on occasion, called "Post clipping alopecia". However it should be a passing condition, and while it can be benign and not a sign of an underlying condition it does warrant further investigation by a vet.

If the vet can not find an underlying cause for the alopecia it might be worth suggesting melatonin treatment to the vet (see: https://www.petmd.com/blogs/dailyvet/2009/december/15-5143 ) Though this should **only** be attempted in cooperation with your vet.

In short I would absolutely bring it up with the vet and get some tests done just to rule out underlying conditions, but this sounds to me to be a benign case of persistent post clipping alopecia.